# The title of an attachment is not working

Tags: filters, conditional-tags, wp-title

I use this function to assign the title of every page:

```
function my_title() {
    switch ( true ) {
        // [...]
        case (is_attachment()):
            wp_title(''); // This doesn't work
            break;
        default :
            wp_title(''); // This works
    }
}
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'my_title', 10, 2 );
```

It seems the conditional `is_attachment()` is not working in this `case`, but it works when it returns the default value. When I say «it's not working» I mean it's not loading the page, it just prints «waiting localhost». At the end it shows:

> Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data. Error
>   code: ERR_EMPT

Why is that?

In the `header.php` file I have this code:

```
<title><?php wp_title(''); ?></title>
```

Any suggestion? I don't know if the problem is the conditional tag, the switch, the filter or the `wp_title()` function. Ah, and I use it into a large function:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'theme_functions', 2);
```

**UPDATE:** LOL, I think I found my mistake. I was using the `wp_title()` function when I had to use `the_title()` into the attachment case. I guess I created a bucle...

Comment: If you have a solution, submit your solution and mark it as such.

Comment: @m0r7if3r, yes. Actually, I just updated the post. I think I created a bucle. Could you confirm if that was my mistake? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not running your code, only you can confirm that a solution worked for you.

Comment: Yep, I think it's ok because it returns the image title attribute. Thanks anyway ;)